# Changing the size of all grace notes with Lilypond

Tags: lilypond, engraving

I am trying to change the size of all grace notes within a staff (or within the score, both would work) while engraving with Lilypond. The documentation on the [grace engraver](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.20/Documentation/internals/grace_005fengraver) is not the most explanatory x__x
I know how to change the size of one grace note, but I'm engraving a score with like, tens and tens, so, not looking forward to do it by hand. Plus, if I suddenly decide to change the size to something else, it won't be very agreeable.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Lilypond, but is there a macro facility? In other words can you define a macro, X = a,b,c, etc., such that every time it comes across #X it replaces it with "a,b,c"? If so then you need to macroize from the start.

Comment: @BrianTowers Lilypond is LISP-based. The *entire language* is a macro facility.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define [global defaults for grace notes](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/notation/special-rhythmic-concerns#Selected-Snippets-36) with `startGraceMusic` and `stopGraceMusic`. The following code:

```
startGraceMusic = {
  <>(
  \override NoteHead.font-size = #3
}

stopGraceMusic = {
  \revert NoteHead.font-size
  <>)
}

\new Staff {
  \relative c'' {
    \grace { b16 } c4
    \grace { b16 } c4
    \grace { b16 } c4
    \grace { b16 } c4
  }
}
```

produces extremely large notes (but I've included it here to see the effect); you probably want `#-3` or something.

[image]

Comment: Actually, I ran into a problem after I accepted that answer. I'm not actually using grace notes (`\grace`), but rather `\slashedGrace` (because they are barred and are not slurred). So I just wrote `startSlashedGraceMusic` and `stopSlashedGraceMusic` instead of `startGraceMusic` and `stopGraceMusic`. But now, my `\slashedGrace` notes are not longer barred, and they are slurred. Any idea how I revert to "normal" behavior (minus note head size) ?

Comment: Perhaps add `\override Flag.stroke-style = #"grace"` (and a corresponding `\revert`)? You can keep using `\grace` then.

Comment: Thanks, it work (for the slash). Do you know off the top of your head, the `override` for the slur (to remove it) ?

Comment: I see [here](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/special-rhythmic-concerns#Selected-Snippets-43) a sample using `\slurDashed` and `\slurSolid`, but I have no idea if there's something like `\slurInvisible`.

Comment: `\slurInvisible` doesn't work, but the doc says that the global defaults are defined in `ly/grace-init.ly` so I gave it a try (to no avail). In that file, it seems that `<>\stopGraceSlur` and `<>\startGraceSlur` are used; defined as `startGraceSlur = #(make-music 'SlurEvent 'span-direction START 'spanner-id 'grace)` and `stopGraceSlur = #(make-music 'SlurEvent 'span-direction STOP 'spanner-id 'grace)`; but I couldn't make anything of it. It's okay, though. I'll stick with the default size of slashed grace notes (if nothing else). Thanks for your time !